# When does the onLoad function of React Native webview execute?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onload

The documentation states that onload is a `Function that is invoked when the WebView has finished loading.`

What action specifically triggers this? Is it fired after all of the scripts within a page have been run or simply when the DOM has finished loading? Is there a callback that executes to tell webview that the page is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

When the DOMContentLoaded event is fired, React Native's webview is kicked off. That would mean that the DOM is finished loading, but the website is not necessarily completely finished loading everything, and is likely continuing to run scripts (if there are any) at this time.